# form/input field-specific validation in object methods (php)

Tags: php, forms, validation, input, error-handling

Lets say we have a regular HTML form with several input fields:

```
<form>

    <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="number" name="amount">

    <buttont type="submit">Send</button>

</form>
```

That form is transmitted and then handled in a class method:

```
function example($user, $password, $email, $amount) {

// Check for all input fields
return "error text";

}
```

So far so good - that works well if you want to display one generic error message nearby the form.

```
// <form> ... </form>

<span style="color:red;">Generic error message</span>
```

But what if you want to display multiple error messages; one for each field?

```
<form>

    <input type="text" name="user">
    <span style="color:red;">user error</span>

    <input type="email" name="email">
    <span style="color:red;">email error</span>

    <input type="password" name="password">
    <span style="color:red;">password error</span>

    <input type="number" name="amount">
    <span style="color:red;">amount error</span>

</form>
```

Is there an efficient way to achieve this? I thought about collecting error messages in an array (within the method), return the array and then check with isset() if there is an error.

```
$errors = example($user, $password, $email, $amount);

<form>

    <input type="text" name="user">

    <?php
    if(isset($errors["user"])) {
    ?>

    <span style="color:red;">user error</span>

    <?php
    }
    ?>

</form>
```

That attempt, however, is bloating the code. Especially when we're talking about multiple forms and tens of different methods. Is there a better solution to achieve what i want?

Comment: You mean like this https://tryphp.w3schools.com/showphp.php?filename=demo_form_validation_special ?

Comment: @DVN-Anakin Visually thats the desired goal, but its way too bloated and not within a class method in your linked example.